# WebFlux from reactive spring to flutter

Tags: json, spring-boot, flutter, dart, reactive

i have a problem while decoding in flutter application/stream+json like this :

```
{ "firstName": "fname1","name": "name1"}
{ "firstName": "fname2","name": "name2"}
{ "firstName": "fname3","name": "name3"}
```

my code is :

```
 Future getuser() async {
      var url = baseUrl + "/test";
      http.Response response= await http.get(url,headers: {"content-type": "application/stream+json"});
      String content=response.body;
      List col=json.decode(content);
      List<User> list=col.map((e) => User.fromMap(e)).toList();   
      return list;
  }
```

the error is unexpected character at line 2 column 1 '{' while decoding json here (json.decode(content))

Comment: actual json should have `[` and `]` surrounding the given `{}` values.

Comment: my backend (spring boot) return stream like the example above , any solution ?

Comment: Is each `{}` entry a single response? or what ? if yes then `json.decode(content)` should give you a map and not a list. So it is either `Map map = json.decode(content);` or `var x = json.decode(content);`  you can use `print(xx.runtimeType);` for it.

Comment: the problem is that the `json.decode(content)` can't decode the json, it send me exception `FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 2, character 1)` because it expected a comma not a `{`

Comment: so it should be `[{},{},{},{}]`

Comment: yes, how to convert it ?

Comment: you don't. the server should return that JSON.

Comment: ok thank you, i will try to modify the server